# Kiel traduki la germanan vorton "Streuselkuchen"?

Tags: translation, food

"Streuselkuchen" estas speco de dolĉa kuko el Germanio. Ĝi estas populara en la suda parto de Brazilo pro la germana migrado, kie oni nomas ĝin "cuca" [kuka]. La ĉefaj ingrediencoj de la kovraĵo estas faruno, sukero kaj butero aŭ margarino. [Ĉi tie estas recepto](https://eo.wikibooks.org/wiki/Kuirlibro:Pomkuko_kun_%22Streusel%22).

Mi trovis komentojn pri tiu vorto ĉe tri paĝoj: [1](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/tradukado/conversations/topics/1243), [2](http://www.ipernity.com/blog/bernardo/140869), [3](http://esperanto-ondo.ru/Recenzoj/R-krause.htm).

Kiel nomi tiun manĝaĵon en Esperanto?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mi memoras, ke estis pri tio diskuto en iu retlisto. La problemo estas, ke tiu speco de kuko-kovraĵo estas kulture specifa (germanlingvujo kaj kelkaj landoj kun germana influo), do eĉ se ekzistas radiko por ĝi, ĝi povus esti por alikulturanoj nekomprenebla, pro la fremda koncepto.

Mi rekomendas en tiaj okazoj uzi pli longan, memklarigan esprimon, ekz. *past-eroj*, la tuta kuko do estus *(gista/mikspasta) kuko kun pastera kovraĵo*. En la ĝusta kunteksto, do ekz. faka libro aŭ kiam vi ofte hejme parolas pri tiaj aferoj (kiel ekz. mi, kiu ofte bakas) kaj do bezonas mallongan esprimon, tiam mi proponas la esprimon *ŝtrejzelo* (el la rusa, origine verŝajne tra la jida el la germana) por la pastero, do *ŝtrejzela kuko*.

Comment: Dankon! Mi sendis tiun demandon al telegrama grupo [Esperantujo](https://t.me/joinchat/AkaBfzvfqSKs_M-crL-1Uw). Marko Flavoĉap (Teserakto) sugestis "ŝtrojzelon" kaj "ŝtrojzelkukon". Almenaŭ ĝi estas tre simila al "ŝtrejzelo". Ĉu la plej ofte uzota vorto aperos en vortaroj?

Comment: Mi ne rekomendus la formon _ŝtrojzelo_, ĉar ĝi estas evidente malpli internacia ol _ŝtrejzelo_, kiu fonetike donas ligon al la rusa (kaj supozebla jida) kaj skribe (_e_) al la germana, dum _ŝtrojzelo_ baziĝas ekskluzive sur la germana elparolo.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ege ŝatas la vorton "ŝtrojzelo" aŭ eĉ "ŝtrojzelo"! Oni bezonas neologismon ĉi-okaze.

Comment: Dankon pro via respondo! Sed vi skribis "ŝtrojzelo" du foje. Kaj oni uzas "bezonas" anstataŭ "necesas". "Necesi" signifas "esti necesa". Vi povas redakti vian respondon. Se vi faros tion, mi forigos ĉi tiun komenton.

Comment: Vi tute pravas, mi ne estis sufiĉe atenta. Fakte, mi preferas la formon kun "o": "ŝtrojzelo". Por Germanoj ĝi sonas same vovaĝe ol "ŝtrejzelo" (sole pro la akcento). Kaj mi ne vidas (do) kial la formo kun "e" estu pli internacia ol tiu kun "e".

Comment: Bone! Ĉu vi volas redakti vian respondon? Klaku sur _"edit"_ por fari tion.

Comment: Bedaŭrinde ne plu estas redaktebla: tro malfrue mi legis tion.

Comment: Mi povas redakti ĝin. Mi ŝanĝis la vorton _"necesas"_ je _"bezonas"_. Sed tiu estos videbla, kiam alia homo konsentos. Mi povas ŝanĝi la unuan frazon je _Mi ege ŝatas la vorton "ŝtrojzelo" aŭ eĉ **"ŝtrejzelo"**_ aŭ _Mi ege ŝatas la vorton **"ŝtrejzelo"** aŭ eĉ "ŝtrojzelo"_. Kiun vi preferas?

Comment: Dankon pro via helpo, Marco

Answer (score 1):

En la angla estus "crumble cake"- pro la dispecigita tavolo.
Mankas (al mi) bela esperanta verbo por esprimi "erŝutita/kovrita kuko".

Comment: La angla kaj mezeŭropaj kukoj tamen esence diferencas per tio, ke en la angla _crumble cake_ la pasteroj estas la malsupra tavolo, do la bazo, dum en la ŝtrejzela kuko ili estas surŝititaj kiel bongustiga/riĉiga tavolo. _crumble cake_ mi nomus simple "pastera kuko".

Comment: @CyrilBrosch dankon pro la klarigo. Serĉinte "Streuselkuchen" la plej ofta formo estas relative seka kuko kun supre sekaj pasteroj sur eble maldika mola tavolo (kvarka, sed eble ankaŭ  marmelada). "Streusel" origine signifis "surŝutaĵo" (de eroj). Aliaj uzoj estas ŝuti salosablon sur la vojoj dumvintre.